# images not showing using spatie media library in filamentphp

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-filament

I am having trouble displaying the images uploaded using spatie media library with the filament admin panel.

[image for clarificatio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkRYa.png)

This is the code for form schema :

```
SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload::make('thumbnail')->collection('posts')
```

And this is the code for table columns

```
SpatieMediaLibraryImageColumn::make('thumbnail')->collection('posts')
```

Thanks.

Comment: im struggling to understand but so far I've gotten to display just 1 image, this means the other responsive images are not being fetched; ```{{ $post->getFirstMediaUrl('thumbnails') }}``` this is how im doing. where you able to display your images, and were they responsive images?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check in your .env (root folder of your laravel project) file that the APP_URL is the same as your server url.
You get the server url on startup (php artisan server) mine is http://127.0.0.1:8000. (or http://localhost:8000)

So you fill in from **APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1** and change to **APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000**
If you have **localhost** fill in **APP_URL=http://localhost:8000**

Check if the files are uploaded to your storgae and been linked with your public folder.
In your CLI: **php artisan storage:link**

Answer (score 5):

You should use:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Yes I use it,  but the problem is still, I think is a server issue but I still don't have any solution for that

Answer (score 1):

Check your APP_URL and take care of the correct port.

Comment: Yes I checked it but the problem is still

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).